# Woocommerce custom theme checkout page not showing

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-theming

I'm creating a custom theme for a woo commerce website. Everything is good except that with my theme when I click on "checkout" in the cart it redirect me on my main page but with the URL of checkout.
If I active a simple theme as twentynineteen then i have my checkout page.
I tried to copy the checkout folder of woocommerce but it does not change anything.
What I don't get is that I don't override anything about this checkout page, so it should inherit from woocommerce and show it.

Here is my theme code: https://bitbucket.org/romain_o/wp-theme-flopo/src/master/

Thanks for your help

Comment: Can you please share website link ?

Comment: Now it's only on localhost

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see page.php template in given theme source code.Can you please create page.php template & make sure to put the_content(); in it. even if i create other pages they are not coming & redirecting to home page.

Comment: Ok thanks that was it ! But then I don't get why when i clicked on a link to a product then it opened the product page and i didn't get this problem. Is this because in that case it's woocommerce which is handling it where as for the checkout it's using wordpress pages ?

Comment: products are displaying because you have created custom template page for products in theme (product.php)